# Selenium VBA: Get the table content which are having <div class elements under <tr and <td

Tags: html, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract the table content from the following HTML code which are listed under <div class. I tried with different codes but i couldn't find the correct solution.

```html
<table class="ISLogIn AvgTotal" id="invoiceAmountAvgTotalNewDesign" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <div class="container invoice-lines-container">
                <div class="list invoice-line-total">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 invoice-line-name">Avg Total</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 invoice-line-name"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-line-value">
                        <strong data-bind="autoNumeric: hasDiscrepancyTotalInvoiceWithDb() ? invoiceAmountDbData().SubTotal : subTotal, autoNumericOptions: $root.moneyNegativeFormat()">135.43</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <div class="container invoice-lines-container">
                <div class="list invoice-line-header">
                    <div class="invoice-line-name col-xs-4" data-bind="css: { 'col-xs-3': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode(), 'col-xs-4': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode() === false }">
                            <span>Sale </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="invoice-line-name col-xs-3" data-bind="css: { 'col-xs-2': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode(), 'col-xs-3': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode() === false }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="invoice-line-value col-xs-4" data-bind="css: { 'col-xs-6': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode(), 'col-xs-4': isEditableAdditionalApprovalCode() === false }"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 invoice-line-value">Amount</div>
                </div>
                <div class="list invoice-line-item-total" data-bind="visible: isInternational()" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 invoice-line-name">Total Sale</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 invoice-line-name"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-line-value">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list invoice-line-item-total" data-bind="visible: !isInternational()">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 invoice-line-name">Total Sale</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 invoice-line-name"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-line-value">
                        <span data-bind="autoNumeric: hasDiscrepancyTotalInvoiceWithDb() ? invoiceAmountDbData().TotalAmountTax : printTaxAmount(), autoNumericOptions: $root.moneyNegativeFormat()">3.14</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <div class="container invoice-lines-container">
                <div class="list invoice-line-total">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 invoice-line-name">Total (<span data-bind="text: workInfo.currency">INR</span>)</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 invoice-line-name"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-line-value">
                        <span data-bind="autoNumeric: calculatedTotal(), autoNumericOptions: $root.moneyNegativeFormat()">138.57</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Below is my vba selenium code which grabs all the row information into one cell.
Im trying to extract as table format. I use chrome with selenium.

```
Option Explicit

Sub table()

Dim d As New ChromeDriver
Dim iM As Object, iMs As Object
Dim S2 As Long, i As Long
    
        d.Get "My URL"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        With Sh2
            Set iMs = d.FindElementsByCss(".ISLogIn AvgTotal div[class^='list invoice-line']")
            .Activate
            For Each iM In iMs
                S2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1: .Cells(S2, 1).Select
                .Cells(S2, 2) = iM.Text
            Next iM
        End With
        Set iM = Nothing:   Set wOrder = Nothing: Set Sc = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Below is the output that im trying for

[image: Output required]

[image]

Please guide me with the correct code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: two things 1)do you need to qualify your xPath with the table class?  If you remove that reference you will get your data from the example provided. However the title and amount values will need to be separated somehow.  2) when valuing S2 your are looking at column 2 but valuing column 1, so it will always return the same value.

Comment: @igittr thank you for your response.. can you please go ahead and remove that reference if you need.. I was in a facing palming situation.. i tried multiple attempts to get that result. For the second point, yes I'm looking at colum 2 where column 1 is having other data...

Comment: @igittr, I changed code for second point.. it should be 2 column.. thanks

Comment: Use the table element id. It is also worth noting that there is an inbuilt method for writing out tables: .AsTable.ToExcel, or if you already declared table as Selenium.Table then just .ToExcel. You then specify the range to write out to

Comment: @igittr, My sincere apologies for late reply, the code worked well. But when i ran this code for multiple urls it is popping an error message. I have included the error image for reference. Kindly can you suggest me how to over come that error message.

Comment: Message comes on line 'Set iT = iM.FindElementByClass("col-xs-4")'.

Comment: @QHarr, Thanks for seeing this query. I tried the method you suggested  .Astable.ToExcel before asking this, unfortunately it grabbed all the row content into one cell.

Comment: The error is the result of the variability of the web page.  When a "Invoice Line" component does not have a "col-xs-4" component, do you want that Invoice line?  Or is that line formatted differently? Is the url using different classes/ids? We cannot help you with such logic, only point you in the right direction.  You may need to use `On Error...` to get around such issues.

Comment: @igittr, can you please update the the code with 'On Error'.. i tried but i couldn't solve it..

Comment: try transferring table element outerHtml via [clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clipboard+table+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get you closer to your solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub table()
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim d As New ChromeDriver
    Dim iM As WebElement, iMs As Object
    Dim sT As String, iV As Selenium.List
    Dim S2 As Long, i As Long
    
    d.Get "your url"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    
    With Sh2
        Set iMs = d.FindElementsByCss("div[class^='list invoice-line']")
        .Activate
        
        For Each iM In iMs
            S2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            sT = getTitle(iM)
            Set iV = iM.FindElementsByClass("invoice-line-value")
            
            For k = 1 To iV.Count
                If iV(k).Text <> "" Then
                    .Cells(S2, 3) = iV(k).Text
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
            .Cells(S2, 2) = sT
        Next iM
    End With
    
    Set iM = Nothing: Set wOrder = Nothing: Set Sc = Nothing
    Set iV = Nothing
    d.Quit
End Sub

Function getTitle(iM As WebElement) As String
    Dim iT As WebElement
    
    On Error GoTo notFnd
    
    Set iT = iM.FindElementByClass("col-xs-4")
    getTitle = iT.Text
    
    Exit Function
    
notFnd:
    getTitle = ""
End Function
```

Comment: @TCritical answer updated with On Error